# How can you search google from imacro and save results?

Tags: imacros

I run my imacro but they does not search some company name directly in google.

CSV File Data:

2Menergia Srl,3E,3M,Deutschland GmbH

The above are company name in csv file i try to search this using imacro and scrape website on google.
But using my code they does not search on google and does not stored data on file.

```
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}},URL GOTO={{!COL1}},
URLGOTO=http://www.google.co.in,
TAG POS=52 TYPE=A ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF,
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}},
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Google_Scrape.csv
```